# 'error' procedure is undefined in plt-r5rs

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I have this file named `myprog.scm`:

```lisp
(error "Not found!")
```

Running the program using `plt-r5rs myprog.scm` gives an error:

```
error: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/pkgs/r5rs-lib/r5rs/run.rkt: [running body]
```

Apparently, [`plt-r5rs`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/plt-r5rs.html) does not define the `error` procedure.

- Why did the authors of `plt-r5rs` not define the `error` procedure?
- How can I define or import an `error` procedure so that my program can run? Perhaps there's a way to import [SRFI-23 *Error reporting mechanism*](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-23/srfi-23.html)?

Comment: Relevant: [DrRacket, R5RS and the error procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3120379)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why did the authors of `plt-r5rs` not define the `error` procedure?

It appears that [The Revised<sup>5</sup> Report on the Algorithmic Language Scheme](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_chap_6) does not define a procedure named `error`. The initial environment created by `plt-r5rs` contains only the values and syntactic forms defined in the report (except for a handful of implementation-specific forms [listed in the docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-mod.html), like `#%require`, which are not legal identifiers according to R<sup>5</sup>RS).

> How can I define or import an `error` procedure so that my program can run? Perhaps there's a way to import SRFI-23 *Error reporting mechanism*?

As you probably know, R<sup>5</sup>RS also does not define a module system, so there is no portable way to import anything. For `plt-r5rs` specifically, this version of your program works:

```lisp
(#%require srfi/23)
(error "Not found!")
```

Of course, if you are relying on details of `plt-r5rs` already, I would suggest just using Racket, or at least R<sup>6</sup>RS.